# CKeditor not working on PythonAnywhere, working on localhost (Django)

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, hosting, pythonanywhere

I have simple blog project that I want to show on pythonanywhere. Unfortunatelly I cant seem to fix issue with CKeditor. It works on localhost, but on pythonanywhere it shows errors and only standard text editor window.

I did try solutions here on Stackoverflow. I did try to run collectstatics etc. Nothing helped so far.

I found that someone said That Pythonanywhere wont ever be able to run CKeditor but I didnt find more about it. If CKeditor is not gonna work, do you know about any other rich text editor that will work? I need one with picture editing.

Also [here](http://esmessica.pythonanywhere.com/) is the webppage on Pythonanywhere.com.

Thank you for any advice.

I will provide code if needed I just didnt know which part exactly would make this issue.

EDIT: errors as text:

```
    Refused to apply style from 'https://esmessica.pythonanywhere.com/static/ckeditor/ckeditor.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
    ckeditor-init.js:1 
            
            
           Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
     Refused to execute script from 'https://esmessica.pythonanywhere.com/static/ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
    ckeditor.js:1 
            
            
           Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
   Refused to execute script from 'https://esmessica.pythonanywhere.com/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
     Refused to apply style from 'https://esmessica.pythonanywhere.com/static/ckeditor/ckeditor.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Comment: please add errors and code as text right into your question, instead of linking images or linking external projects

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I added the errors

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve the static files for CKEditor. See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/StaticFiles/